# Cannot resolve method 'execute()' in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I am trying to implement `Circular ProgressBar` in one of my `fragment`.

I want to attain this using `AsyncTask` class along with other background process and I want that `progress bar` to update on `onProgressUpdate()` method too.

Here's my Fragment implementing ProgressBar:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_fragment, container, false);

    // Setting up progressBar
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setProgress(0);

    return rootView;
}
```

Calling `AsyncTask` class from within Fragment which says cannot resolve method at `setProgressBr()`. I think I am not appropriately passing the parameters.

```
new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext(),PlaylistFragment.this)
                .setProgressBar(progressBar)
                .execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
```

Here's my AsyncTask class:

```
    public class GetPlaylistAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Pair<String, List<Video>>> {
    private static final String TAG = "GetPlaylistAsyncTask";
    private static final Long YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS = 10L;

    //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list
    private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART = "snippet";
    private static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS = "pageInfo,nextPageToken,items(id,snippet(resourceId/videoId))";
    //see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list
    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART = "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"; // video resource properties that the response will include.
    private static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS = "items(id,snippet(title,description,thumbnails/high),contentDetails/duration,statistics)"; // selector specifying which fields to include in a partial response.

    private YouTube mYouTubeDataApi;
    Context mContext;
    ProgressBar bar;

    private AsyncResponse theListener;

    public void setProgressBar(ProgressBar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public GetPlaylistAsyncTask(YouTube api, Context context, PlaylistFragment frag ) {
        mYouTubeDataApi = api;
        mContext = context;
        theListener = (AsyncResponse)frag;
    }


    @Override
    protected Pair<String, List<Video>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        final String playlistId = params[0];
        final String nextPageToken;

        if (params.length == 2) {
            nextPageToken = params[1];
        } else {
            nextPageToken = null;
        }

        PlaylistItemListResponse playlistItemListResponse;
        try {
            playlistItemListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.playlistItems()
                    .list(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_PART)
                    .setPlaylistId(playlistId)
                    .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                    .setFields(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_FIELDS)
                    .setMaxResults(YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST_MAX_RESULTS)
                    .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                    .execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        if (playlistItemListResponse == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get playlist");
            return null;
        }

        List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList();

        // pull out the video id's from the playlist page
        for (PlaylistItem item : playlistItemListResponse.getItems()) {
            videoIds.add(item.getSnippet().getResourceId().getVideoId());
        }

        // get details of the videos on this playlist page
        VideoListResponse videoListResponse = null;
        try {
            videoListResponse = mYouTubeDataApi.videos()
                    .list(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_PART)
                    .setFields(YOUTUBE_VIDEOS_FIELDS)
                    .setKey(ApiKey.YOUTUBE_API_KEY)
                    .setId(TextUtils.join(",", videoIds)).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new Pair(playlistItemListResponse.getNextPageToken(), videoListResponse.getItems());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (this.bar != null) {
            bar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Pair<String, List<Video>> result) {
        theListener.handleGetPlaylistResult(null,result);
    }
}
```

Will appreciate a quick fix for the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.setProgressBar(progressBar)` method has a return type void so you cannot chain the calls like this

```
new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext(),PlaylistFragment.this)
                .setProgressBar(progressBar)
                .execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
```

Change your `setProgressBar()` method to the following and it should work

```
public GetPlaylistAsyncTask setProgressBar(ProgressBar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        return this;
}
```

OR

If you don't want to change the method signature then do the following

```
final GetPlaylistAsyncTask getPlaylistAsyncTask = new GetPlaylistAsyncTask(mYouTubeDataApi,getContext(),PlaylistFragment.this);
getPlaylistAsyncTask.setProgressBar(progressBar);
getPlaylistAsyncTask.execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
```

Also make sure both params `playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken()` are Strings.

Comment: Can you please mark it as an answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: Its working fine but its not updating the values of progressBar onProgressUpdate ...

Comment: @ LeoNeo Can you please explain why onProgressUpdate method is not getting called.

Comment: Oh .. I am not calling publishProgress anywhere !

Comment: Well Thank you for your time and consideration. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes you'll have to decide for yourself how to calibrate the metrics for deciding the progress on the progress bar and call publishProgress accordingly. e.g if it's downloading a file from a source then you can put it in a stream and for every byte/char that is downloaded you call publish progress and finally finish it when the download completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
GetPlaylistAsyncTask playAsync=new (mYouTubeDataApi,getContext(),PlaylistFragment.this);
playAsync.setProgressBar(progressBar);
playAsync.execute(playlistVideos.playlistId, playlistVideos.getNextPageToken());
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling methods in chain . In that way each method should returns the current instance on which its called . Modify your method as below it will work.

```
public GetPlaylistAsyncTask setProgressBar(ProgressBar bar) {
this.bar = bar;
return this;
}
```

Comment: Yes its working fine but progress in not getting updated on onProgressUpdate. Any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just add progress directly to a circular progress bar, Here is what I did to resolve this issue.

add a drawable file circular_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius ="15dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thickness="4dp" >
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/blackBackground"
            android:startColor="@color/blackBackground"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadius ="15dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:useLevel="true"
            android:thickness="4dp">
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="360" />

            <gradient
                android:endColor="#e1c25b"
                android:startColor="#e1c25b"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

in your fragment layout add a progress bar

```
 <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pb_download"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="75"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />
```

now you can use setProgress() to update the progress.
Feel free to ask any doubts.

Comment: I am doing the same thing.